# PayPal API - Increase Order Amount after Authorisation. Best Checkout Flow?

Tags: php, paypal, braintree

We are using the PayPal / Braintree API.

What is the correct way of dealing with an increasing order amount (example: delivery costs), after the original order amount has been authorised?

Ideally, we want to send the customer to PayPal once, then they select their preferred delivery on our delivery page, without then sending the customer back to PayPal to ReAuth.

Is this possible?

The delivery amounts can be fairly large, that would take it above the 115% / $75 restrictions.

Thanks.

Comment: So complete all you question flow BEFORE going to paypal, so you can issue one transaction with all the items INCLUDING shipping on it

Answer (score 0):

> after the original order amount has been authorised?

Don't do that?

After payment is *approved* by the payer, but before authorising a transaction, show a review step. Use the selected address to calculate any applicable shipping and tax. Offer a choice of shipping methods if applicable.

When the new total is calculated, and when the user gives final confirmation, create the braintree transaction with the new amount ([PayPal payment method in Braintree](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/paypal/server-side), or [more generally with Braintree](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/reference/request/transaction/sale)). This is analogous to using the non-Braintree PayPal REST API to capture an order with an updated (patched) amount.

One final detail is that since you have a review step after approval, if using the PayPal SDK you should set commit: false (it defaults to true) so that the last button has the correct verbiage indicating there is a further step on returning to your site. With Braintree this looks something like:

```
paypalCheckoutInstance.loadPayPalSDK({
  intent: ????????? , // Braintree defaults this to 'authorize'
  currency: 'USD',
  commit: false,
```

Comment: The reason I do this is to avoid getting the customer to enter their details manually (delivery address etc...), Which we need (and get from PayPal after auth) to show them their delivery options. I don't see any way around it unless we can 'Patch' the order (not sure if this will work), or we cancel the previous Auth and re-auth after the delivery page.

Comment: The flow I've described satisfies everything you just said so I'm not sure what you're unclear about. Get their details after approval, before review, before adjusting the amount, and before creating the transaction.